# Explain how generics work in this method

Tags: java, generics

I have been working on Google AdWords and came across this code

*adwords-api-6.4.0, com.google.api.adwords.lib.AdWordsUser*

```
public <T extends java.rmi.Remote> T getService(AdWordsService service) throws ServiceException {
    try {
      return (T) AdWordsServiceFactory.generateSerivceStub(service, this,
          service.getEndpointServer(this.isUsingSandbox()), false);
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
      throw new ServiceException("Cannot cast serivce. Check the type of return-capture variable.", e);
    }
}
```

which is invoked like this:

```
AdWordsUser user = new AdWordsUser();
AdGroupServiceInterface adGroupService = user.getService(AdWordsService.V200909.ADGROUP_SERVICE);
```

Could you please explain how generics work in ***getService*** method? How is the return type determined?
What is the purpose of such usage? It doesn't seem like it provides type safety.
Does this usage have a specific name (so I could find more info on it and change the question title)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A compiler may often infer the return type from the calling context. In the example provided, the compiler infers that the generic type is `AdGroupServiceInterface` because the result is being assigned to that type. If no context is available from which the return type can be inferred, it must be specified explicitly:

```
user.<AdGroupServiceInterface>getService(svc);
```

However, the `getService` method is *not* type-safe. Even though it contains a cast, this is only ensuring that the result implements the `java.rmi.Remote` interface. Because of type erasure in Java generics, the exact type `T` is not known, and the cast can't check to make sure that the result is `AdGroupServiceInterface`.

That's why a compiler will warn about the unsafe cast—a `ClassCastException` will be raised when the result is assigned to the `AdGroupServiceInterface` variable, not inside the method and its catch block.

Answer (score 2):

I know more about C# than Java, but I'd guess that the `getService` method takes a parameter of type `AdWordsService`, and returns a type `T`, which must derive from `java.rmi.Remote`.

Presumably the `AdWordsServiceFactory.generateSerivceStub` method return type is of type `java.rmi.Remote` or similar, so it would be legal to cast this into the `T` type.

In C#, generics are used in this way to avoid casting, but the casting's still taking place here. I guess with this particular method, it's saving you from having to cast to your desired type, by making you tell the generic method exactly what type you want back.

I would also imagine that you need to specify the type of `T` in your call to `getService`. Maybe like this?

```
AdGroupServiceInterface adGroupService = user.getService<AdGroupServiceInterface>(AdWordsService.V200909.ADGROUP_SERVICE);
```

Comment: in java rather *user.<AdGroupServiceInterface>getService (...)*